# Finding Specific Table from Website by String using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

[Picture Of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EdvE.jpg)

I have been trying to extract a table from a website, only if the table contains a specific substring.

I use requests to open a URL and the pandas.html to extract the tables. However, by doing this, I either extract all tables or a specific table by index and I want to find a way to only extract the table that has my keyword.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

#url is the website, html opens the site and df_list is extracting all tables

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/880432/000114420415073214/v427721_def14a.htm'

html = requests.get(url).content

df_list = pd.read_html(html)
```

From here I can print `df_list[index]` but I want the table with my keyword. I have tried the following: (none return anything)

```
for i in range(len(df_list)):
    if 'Fees Earned' in df_list:
        print (df_list[i])

for i in range(len(df_list)):
    if any("Fees Earned" in s for s in df_list):
        print(df_list[i])
```

If I try:

```
print(any(sub in mystring for mystring in mylist))
```

I only receive the output "False"

Comment: Which problem is more critical for you: doing this with Pandas or doing this in the first place?  That is, would you be fine with a non-Pandas solution?  BeautifulSoup might be very helpful here.

Comment: I don't really care about doing it with pandas as long as I can get a table that I later will be able to extract to excel, I am open to any solution! :)

Comment: When you say the "table with my keyword" what do you mean?  Will the keyword be the text of a specific cell?  The header?  In a class or id variable?

Comment: However, it needs to be in a way that I can do it for several links (of the same type).

Comment: The keyword is "Fees Earned" and it is one of the subheaders in the table. I only want the table where that string is present.

Comment: Can you provide a (small) sample table that shows the kind of header you're talking about?

Comment: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/880432/000114420415073214/v427721_def14a.htm

On the website above, on page 7, is the table I want to extract.

Comment: I have added a link to a picture of the table in the original question now aswell.

Comment: I've found the table myself in the code.  For future reference, sample code is usually more helpful than a picture.

Comment: Okay good, thank you for the advice! df_link[38] would show the link in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the table:

```
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.select_one('table:contains("Fees Earned")')
```

To convert it into a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
```

You'll probably want to clean up the table before you export it to excel.

Comment: I receive the following error when running it:

NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: What version of bs4 do you have installed?  Is it lower than 4.7.1?  Does it work if you update it?

Comment: why reach all the way back up when you can do table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table:contains("Fees Earned")')))
 ?

Comment: @QHarr no particular reason, just stylistic habit; I've edited it.  For posterity: original was `soup.select_one('td:contains("Fees Earned")').parent.parent`.

Comment: You were right! My bs4 was not updated, it is updated now and it works. Thank you so much!!

Comment: If I have several URL:s, is there a way to make this code into a loop so it outputs one table from each site?

Comment: @FilipKrueger definitely.  Just put the urls into a for loop: `for url in urls:`,  `with requests.get(url).content as html`, then run the code as above.

Comment: Thank you very much!! The only issue I have is that the tables do not seem to be appended properly into a list. I want to export all the tables to excel and it does not seem to work.

Comment: I'd suggest using [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
for df in df_list:
   new_df=df.dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1,how='any')
   if "Fees Earned" in str(df.iloc[:,:]):
        print(new_df)
```